# Python string comparison function with input, while loop, and if/else statment

Tags: python-3.x, string, function, input, while-loop

I'm trying to create a program that takes input from the user, -1 or 1 to play or quit, number of characters (n), two words for comparison (s1,s2), and calls this function: `def strNcompare (s1,s2,n)` and then prints the result. The function should return 0,-1,1 if n-character portion of s1 is equal to, less than, or greater than the corresponding n-character of s2, respectively. So for example is the first string is equal to the second string, it should return a 0.

The loop should end when the user enters, -1.

I'm just starting out in Python so the code I have is pretty rough. I know I need an if/else statement to print the results using the return value of the function and a while loop to make the program run.

This is what I have so far, it by no means works but my knowledge ends here. I don't know how to integrate the character (n) piece at all either.

```
com = input ("String comparison [1(play), -1(quit)]: ")

while (com=='1'):
 s1 = input ("enter first string: ") 
 s2 = input ("enter second string: ") 
 n = int(input("number of characters: ")
 s1 = s1[:n]
 s1 = s2[:n]

 if com==-1:
  break

def strNcompare(s1,s2,n):
 return s1==s2

 elif s1==s2:
  print(f'{s1} is equal to {s2}')
 elif s1>s2:
  print (f'{s1} is greater than {s2}')
 elif s1<s2:
  print (f'{s1} is less than {s2}')
 else: 
  print ("QUIT")
 break 

com = input ("String comparison [1(play), -1(quit)]: ")
```

As of 10/05/2019 - I revised the code and now I am getting a syntax error at "s1 = s1[:n]"

Answer (score 0):

it did not made much sense and especially the variable 'n' is not completely clear to me. I would not code it like that but I tried to be as close to your logic as possible.

```
com = input ("String comparison [1(play), -1(quit)]: ")

while (com=='1'):
  s1 = input ("enter first string: ") 
  s2 = input ("enter second string: ") 
  n = input ("number of characters: ") #what is the purpose of this? 

  if s1==s2:
      print(f'{s1} is equal than {s2}')
  elif s1>s2:
      print (f'{s1} is greater than {s2}')
  elif s1<s2:
      print (f'{s1} is less than {s2}')
  else: 
      print ("Error")
```

Comment: The n is the number of characters entered by the user. So say the user enters 3, the first three characters of each string should be compared. This is a concept I completely don’t understand.

Comment: Also the printed solution to the program, for example “s1 is greater than s2”, is created as a result of the return 0,-1,1 from the function once the comparison is made. This is just something that’s part of the program even though it’s not really necessary. That’s why I created that if/else statement with the return and tried to tie it in to another if/else statement that prints the result.